# geoserver wfs-t is read-only exception

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am trying to save changes via WFS-T using GeoServer:
This is my code that is getting feature from geoserver

```
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/kairosDB/ows', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'getFeature',
                typename: 'wfs_geom',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    // strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()),
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

And This is code that is saving feature to server

```
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/kairosDB',
    featureType: 'wfs_geom',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

But When I saveFeature to server, This error's occured

```
2017-02-01 14:30:02,339 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: {http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/kairosDB}wfs_geom is read-only
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:269)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:106)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor195.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

wfs_geom table already has a primary key, create script:

```
CREATE TABLE public.wfs_geom
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    geometry geometry,
    CONSTRAINT wfs_geom_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.wfs_geom
    OWNER to postgres;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.wfs_geom TO postgres;

-- Index: sidx_wfs_geom

-- DROP INDEX public.sidx_wfs_geom;

CREATE INDEX sidx_wfs_geom
    ON public.wfs_geom USING gist
    (geometry)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Read-only-error-when-editing-a-WFS-T-td5284537.html

> There is a rule in the "Data security" section that do allow to write
>   to this workspace for all, but the writing is not allowed to anonymous
>   user for all the workspace (*.*.w) The strange behaviour is that in
>   yesterday I can edit the layer using a client.. and I do not
>   understand why, moreover using QGIS I cannot edit the layer, but QGIS
>   support the WFS-T

Comment: it most likely works in your browser because you have logged in as admin in that or another tab, while QGis hasn't logged in

Comment: I use postgis and, I logged in postgis, and also my browser has logged in geoserver, but error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to change in GeoServer to makes this possible.

1. Enable Transactional under the WFS tab on GeoServer
2. Under the Data tab on GeoServer you need to edit the rule ..w to enable the role ROLE_ANONYMOUS

After doing these two things I was able to get rid of this error and post data to GeoServer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a primary key constraint to the table.